# Compare Values across few columns in r dataframe

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
pr1  tr     pr2   tp    pr3  pr4 
A    tt      B    34     C    C
A    tg      A    45     A    B
K    hj      H    45     I    J
B    jk      1    67     2    3
0    12      0    78     A    A
```

I want to compare values in the `pr1`, `pr2`, `pr3`, and `pr4` columns for every row and add a new column stating 1 if any value is repeated twice or more in any of the column or stating 0. I don't want the `tr` and `tp` columns to be part of comparison. The output dataframe should be like below, and has a `temp` column indicating 1 or 0.

```
pr1  tr     pr2  tr3    pr3  pr4  temp
A    tt     B    34     C    C    1
A    tg     A    45     A    B    1
K    hj     H    45     I    J    0
B    jk     1    67     2    3    0
0    12     0    78     A    A    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `anyDuplicated` by looping through the rows

```
df1$temp <- as.integer(apply(df1[grepl("pr\\d+", names(df1))], 1, FUN = anyDuplicated) >0)
df1$temp
#[1] 1 1 0 0 1
```